# RxJava: React for event or wait if other event performed and then react

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I try to apply RxJava to my android application. The problem is with reaction on events while previous event still performing.

I've stuck with using `BehaviorSubject` on my fragment. I create the field on my class:

```
private BehaviorSubject<EventObject> behaviorSubject;
```

In `onCreate()` method I assign `behaviorSubject`:

```
behaviorSubject
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(eventObject -> {
         move(eventObject );
    }, t -> ToastErrorHandler.handle(getContext(), t));
```

Let's consider scenario:

1. The event come, so I invoke:

   ```
       behaviorSubject.onNext(eventObject);
   ```
2. I would like to invoke method `move(eventObject);`.

The method `move(eventObject)` perform exactly 2 seconds. During this time, another event can come. I would like the second event will wait until first event not perform completely.

How to handle above scenario in RxJava?